# Problem with LangChain program displaying error: AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGALRM'

Tags: python, streamlit, huggingface, langchain

I'm getting this error when I test HuggingFace's local model falcon-7b-instruct:

AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGALRM'

I am using streamlit, and I think streamlit is using signal which might be causing this error. I am running this on Windows, and from what I read, signal.SIGALRM only works with Unix machines. That shouldn't matter in my case however because you can use streamlit on Windows.

Here is my code for reference:

```
`from langchain.llms import HuggingFacePipeline
 import torch
 from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, pipeline, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
            model_id = 'tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct'
            tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
            model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_id)
            
            pipe = pipeline(
                "text2text-generation",
                model=model,
                tokenizer=tokenizer,
                max_length=100
            )

            chat = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)

            #chat = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct", model_kwargs={"temperature": temperature, "max_new_tokens": 1000}) # HuggingFace models do not like temperature = 

        # We create a RetrievalQA by passing it our vectordb and llm
        qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=chat, chain_type="stuff", retriever=db.as_retriever())
        st.success(qa.run(query))`
```

Truthfully, I expected it to work as a regular HuggingFaceHub object, but I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

While that signal is not supported on Windows, you should be able to read the stack trace and determine what conditional branch lead to it attempting to be fired. In my case, it looked like this:

```
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\transformers\dynamic_module_utils.py:535, in resolve_trust_remote_code(trust_remote_code, model_name, has_local_code, has_remote_code)
    533     trust_remote_code = False
    534 elif has_remote_code and TIME_OUT_REMOTE_CODE > 0:
--> 535     signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _raise_timeout_error)
    536     signal.alarm(TIME_OUT_REMOTE_CODE)
    537     while trust_remote_code is None:
```

Googling the has_remote_code variable lead me to the [trust_remote_code](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/auto) model kwarg, which got me past the error. So give perhaps give this a try if your stack trace is similar to mine:

```
 pipe = pipeline(
            "text2text-generation",
            model=model,
            tokenizer=tokenizer,
            trust_remote_code=True,
            max_length=100
        )
```